# Unable to have AWS lambda wait till asynchronous request call is completed

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, async-await, aws-lambda

I am here with a same/similar problem in understanding asynchronous calls in AWS Lambda Node 8.10.  Below is my code.  It runs, but not as I want it.  I am attempting to get the HTTPS header and the associated SSL certificate.  If I run the lambda once, it runs successfully, but no data.  If I test it over and over, one of the returns comes back and getPeerCertificate outputs to the log.

Here is where I scratch my head...there is a callback function defined `res`. I believe what is occurring is the lambda vanishes before the callback is called from the `request`.  I am struggling in how to keep the lambda alive to await the return from the request.  I am trying to make this a minimal as possible (no additional modules).  Any asynchers out there who can help?

```
exports.handler = async (event) => {
    console.log(event);
    var https = require('https');

    var options = {
        method: 'HEAD',
        hostname: 'google.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/'
    };

    try {
        var req = https.request(options, (res) => {
            console.log(res.connection.getPeerCertificate());
        });

        req.end();

    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use the callback function of your lambda as this :

```
const https = require('https');

exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {
    console.log(event);

    const options = {
        method: 'HEAD',
        hostname: 'google.com',
        port: 443,
        path: '/'
    };

    const req = https.request(options, (res) => {
        res.on('data', (d) => {
            callback(null, d);
        });
    });

    req.on('error', (e) => {
        callback(e);
    });

    req.end();
}
```

An other solution should be to explicitly declare a promise.

Comment: Why `req.end();`?  What does that do?

Comment: Thank you David.  Was trying to use the new async construct instead of the older callback.  I am progressing on a declared promise. Chugging through and learning lots!

Comment: Hello Michael, `req.end();` is required to close the request.  Unlike a `.get()`, a `.request()` is open till closed.